# Ipython Notebook Widget displays 'None' (the return value)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have the following (example) code to display a widget and update a value based on the widget.  It works fine, except in my Ipython notebook, None is displayed at the end (which is what was returned from my function).  How do I hide that/ return something that won't be displayed?

```
from ipywidgets import widgets, interact, interactive
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

opts = 'dog'
def update_val(a):
    ValuesWidget.options = [a]

ArrayWidget = interactive(update_val,a=widgets.Dropdown(description="Pick an animal: ",options=['dog','cat','mouse']))
ValuesWidget = widgets.Dropdown(description="Display this value: ",options=[opts])
display(ArrayWidget,ValuesWidget)
```

If I do a 'return 5' at the end of the function five is displayed instead, so I know the issue is with the return value of the function.

Comment: The use of `interactive` returns a value by default. Are you set on using `interact`? perhaps using `link` you can achieve the same goal

Answer (score -1):

In the code you're posting, you aren't returning anything so it's returning `None` by default. Try using:

```
return ValuesWidget.options = [a]
```

Comment: This generates a SyntaxError